How to make rectangular images using Matplotlib as some functions are not recognized?
I'm trying to make rectangular annotations on images, but I'm unable to put annotation as I'm running into attribute errors as some modules are not recognized, the file directory has images in .jpeg, and I want to make a interface on Jupyter notebook to make selection on images or you can say rectangular annotations.
The code is:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from PIL import Image
from IPython.display import display, clear_output
import ipywidgets as widgets
import os

class ImageAnnotator:
    def _init_(self):
        self.image_dir = "C:\\\\annotated_images"
        self.images = []
        self.current_index = 0
        self.rect_coords = []
        self.rect_active = False
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.ax.axis('off')
        self.canvas = self.fig.canvas

        self.load_button = widgets.Button(description="Load Images")
        self.load_button.on_click(self.load_images)
        self.prev_button = widgets.Button(description="Previous (P)")
        self.prev_button.on_click(self.previous_image)
        self.next_button = widgets.Button(description="Next (N)")
        self.next_button.on_click(self.next_image)
        self.redo_button = widgets.Button(description="Redo (R)")
        self.redo_button.on_click(self.redo_annotation)
        self.enable_annotation_button = widgets.Button(description="Enable Annotation")
        self.enable_annotation_button.on_click(self.enable_annotation)

        self.file_path_entry = widgets.Text(value=self.image_dir, description="File Path:", disabled=True)

        self.output = widgets.Output()

        self.display_widgets()

    def display_widgets(self):
        display(self.file_path_entry)
        display(self.load_button)
        display(widgets.HBox([self.prev_button, self.next_button, self.redo_button]))
        display(self.enable_annotation_button)
        display(self.output)

    def load_images(self, _):
        self.images = [file for file in os.listdir(self.image_dir) if file.endswith('.jpg') or file.endswith('.jpeg')]
        if self.images:
            self.current_index = 0
            self.show_image()

    def show_image(self):
        image_path = os.path.join(self.image_dir, self.images[self.current_index])
        self.file_path_entry.value = image_path
        self.image = Image.open(image_path)
        self.ax.clear()
        self.ax.imshow(self.image)
        self.canvas.draw()

    def previous_image(self, _):
        if self.current_index > 0:
            self.current_index -= 1
            self.show_image()

    def next_image(self, _):
        if self.current_index < len(self.images) - 1:
            self.current_index += 1
            self.show_image()

    def redo_annotation(self, _):
        self.rect_coords = []
        self.rect_active = False
        self.ax.clear()
        self.ax.imshow(self.image)
        self.canvas.draw()

    def enable_annotation(self, _):
        self.rect_coords = []
        self.rect_active = True

    def on_canvas_click(self, event):
        if not self.rect_active:
            return
        x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata
        self.rect_coords.append((x, y))
        if len(self.rect_coords) == 2:
            self.draw_rectangle()

    def draw_rectangle(self):
        x1, y1 = self.rect_coords[0]
        x2, y2 = self.rect_coords[1]
        width = abs(x2 - x1)
        height = abs(y2 - y1)
        rect = patches.Rectangle((x1, y1), width, height, linewidth=2, edgecolor='r', facecolor='none')
        self.ax.add_patch(rect)
        self.rect_coords = []
        self.rect_active = False
        self.canvas.draw()

# Instantiate and display the ImageAnnotator
annotator = ImageAnnotator()
annotator.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', annotator.on_canvas_click)
display(annotator.fig.canvas)

I wanted an interactive rectangular annotator, but I'm running into loads of errors

Please clearly explain what you mean by "lots of errors" "some modules are not recognized". Please add full stack trace.
